# finding and returning a string with a specified prefix

Tags: python, regex, string

I am close but I am not sure what to do with the restuling match object. If I do

```
p = re.search('[/@.* /]', str)
```

I'll get any words that start with @ and end up with a space. This is what I want. However this returns a Match object that I dont' know what to do with. What's the most computationally efficient way of finding and returning a string which is prefixed with a @?

For example,

```
"Hi there @guy"
```

After doing the proper calculations, I would be returned

```
guy
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following regular expression do what you need:

```
import re
s = "Hi there @guy"
p = re.search(r'@(\w+)', s)
print p.group(1)
```

It will also work for the following string formats:

- `s = "Hi there @guy "` # notice the trailing space
- `s = "Hi there @guy,"` # notice the trailing comma
- `s = "Hi there @guy and"` # notice the next word
- `s = "Hi there @guy22"` # notice the trailing numbers
- `s = "Hi there @22guy"` # notice the leading numbers

Comment: Depends on whether `'let's meet @11pm'` should get matched

Comment: If numbers were significant (as well as words) how would that regex be modified?

Comment: Actually the \w pattern matches any alphanumeric character and the underscore, this is equivalent to the set [a-zA-Z0-9_] so @11pm for example would be matched correctly.

Answer (score 1):

That regex does not do what you think it does.

```
s = "Hi there @guy"
p = re.search(r'@([^ ]+)', s) # this is the regex you described
print p.group(1) # first thing matched inside of ( .. )
```

But as usually with regex, there are tons of examples that break this, for example if the text is `s = "Hi there @guy, what's with the comma?"` the result would be `guy,`.

So you really need to think about every possible thing you want and don't want to match. `r'@([a-zA-Z]+)'` might be a good starting point, it literally only matches letters (a .. z, no unicode etc).

Answer (score 0):

`p.group(0)` should return `guy`. If you want to find out what function an object has, you can use the `dir(p)` method to find out. This will return a list of attributes and methods that are available for that object instance.

Comment: doesn't seem to, 

`>>> str = "Jo there @guy"
>>> p = re.search('[/@.* /]', str)
>>> p.group(0)
' '`

(the output is ' ')

Comment: I will add that you can find the documentation of the match object at http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#match-objects

Answer (score 0):

```
(?<=@)\w+
```

will match a word if it's preceded by a `@` (without adding it to the match, a so-called positive lookbehind). This will match "words" that are composed of letters, numbers, and/or underscore; if you don't want those, use `(?<=@)[^\W\d_]+`

In Python:

```
>>> strg = "Hi there @guy!"
>>> p = re.search(r'(?<=@)\w+', strg)
>>> p.group()
'guy'
```

Answer (score 0):

As it's evident from the answers so far regex is the most efficient solution for your problem. Answers differ slightly regarding what you allow to be followed by the `@`:

```
[^ ] anything but space
\w   in python-2.x is equivalent to [A-Za-z0-9_], in py3k is locale dependent
```

If you have better idea what characters might be included in the user name you might adjust your regex to reflect that, e.g., only lower case ascii letters, would be:

```
[a-z]
```

NB: I skipped quantifiers for simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

You say: """If I do `p = re.search('[/@.* /]', str)` I'll get any words that start with @ and end up with a space."" But this is incorrect -- that pattern is a character class which will match ONE character in the set `@/.*` and space. Note: there's a redundant second `/` in the pattern.
For example:

```
>>> re.findall('[/@.* /]', 'xxx@foo x/x.x*x xxxx')
['@', ' ', '/', '.', '*', ' ']
>>>
```

You say that you want `"guy"` returned from `"Hi there @guy"` but that conflicts with "and end up with a space".

Please edit your question to include what you really want/need to match.